# Inserting a program listing with R code chunk NOT to be executed in LyX

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

This is what I am trying to accomplish in LyX:

1. I want to insert this piece of code as a program listing by using an Algorithm Float (Insert > Float > Algorithm) and then a Program Lisiting inside the Algorithm float (Insert > Program Listing).
2. The code that I wish to insert is this:

> ```
> <<A-simple-plot>>=
> x<-rnorm(10)
> y<-rnorm(10)
> plot(x,y)
> @
> ```

3. The output that I get after compiling it is:

> ```
> \ begin { knitrout }
> \ d e f i n e c o l o r { shadecolor }{ rgb }{0.969 ,
> 0.969 ,
> 0.969}\ color { f g c o l o r }\ begin {kframe}
> \ begin { a l l t t }
> \ hlstd {x}\hlkwb{<=}\hlkwd{rnorm}\ hlstd {(}\hlnum{10}\ hlstd {)}
> \ hlstd {y}\hlkwb{<=}\hlkwd{rnorm}\ hlstd {(}\hlnum{10}\ hlstd {)}
> \hlkwd{ plot }\ hlstd {(x , y)}
> \end{ a l l t t }
> \end{kframe}
> \ includegraphics [ width=\maxwidth ]{ f i g u r e /unnamed=chunk=3=1}
> \end{ knitrout }
> ```

This is clearly not what I want...  I haven't checked the Verbatim package...

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this?

Update: Minimal Working Example @scottkosty

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
knitr
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Minimal Working Example with Knitr Program Listing using Algorithm Floats
 in LyX
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Diego A.
 Acosta M., PhD
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
2024-01-10
\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
This is a minimal working example of a LyX article that aims at including
 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 and executing 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 code chunks and showing a program listing of an 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 code chunk without executing it.
 For this to happen the module Rnw (knitr) needs to be added to this document
 (Document ▷ Settings ▷ Modules ▷ Rnw (knitr)) as well as have knitr installed
 in 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

.
 The path 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 needs to be correctly specified.
 The Document Class is Article (Standard Class.) Let's get to the problem
 at hand.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
A simple 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 code chunk
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

1+1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
That one ran OK.
 Let's create a program listing to display the complete code of the above
 chunk using Figure (See 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "CodeinFigure"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset

), Table (See 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "CodeinTable"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset

) and Algorithm floats:
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset listings
inline false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

1+1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Including the code inside a Figure
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "CodeinFigure"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float table
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset listings
inline false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

1+1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Including program listing inside a Table
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "CodeinTable"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float algorithm
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset listings
inline false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

1+1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Including program listing in Algorithm
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "CodeinAlgorithm"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
This was the process: Insert ▷ Float ▷ Figure, Table, Algorithm whichever
 applicable.
 Then, inside the float, Insert ▷ Program Listing...
 I just copy-pasted the code inside the knitr chunk...
 Preview doesn't render the floats correctly...
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: It looks like you want to use knitr, but a LaTeX "program listing" is not knitr (from what I know). Take a look at Help > Specific Manuals > Knitr. If you don't want it to be executed in LyX, just use the knitr chunk option "eval = FALSE".

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. No, I don't want to use knitr in this case: I want to be able to provide an example of a knitr chunk inside an algorithm float in a LyX document (I am aware of the modules that I need to use in LyX and the package that I need to install in R.) I just want the verbatim program listing as shown in my question.

Comment: I see. Can you post a minimal example .lyx file so I can take a look? Then ping me (use `@` followed by my user name). See here for more information: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty it is the very first time that I try to do this.  How can I upload the lyx file?

Comment: Please read the link, at the part "How do I post a .lyx file...".

Comment: Thanks for adding that example. I can reproduce what you describe. A couple of ideas: (1) do you need to evaluate knitr chunks as well? If not, you could just remove the knitr module. I'm guessing you want to do both (evaluate and list the algorithm) so this idea won't work. (2) After searching I found this: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/verbatim-code-chunks.html but I tried it in the LyX document and it didn't work as expected. I'm sorry I couldn't figure out a solution.

Comment: @scottkosty Thank you very very much for your time and effort.  What I am going to do is what you suggested and remove the knitr heading...  That's all I can do for now...  I am going to explore the verbatim package and see if I can figure it out... Perhaps a minipage? I will try, this shouldn't be complicated! Again, thank you so very much...

Comment: I experimented and created a LyX file without the Rnw module and made an algorithm float with a knitr chunk... When I ran the thing the program listing was shown correctly... Then, I added the Rnw module and the problem resurfaced as with the minimal working example that I showed... I don't know if that hints to something...

Comment: The root problem is that knitr is essentially a "pre-processor". It sees the file before LaTeX gets it, and it just searches for the "begin chunk" and "end chunk" markers. I'm not sure how to work around it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

@scottkosty I found a workaround that's just horrible but does the trick using a frameless box inside an algorithm float.  Here's a minimal example:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
knitr
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
A horrible workaround
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Diego A.
 Acosta M., PhD
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
2024-01-15
\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
This is a horrible workaround to solve a question I asked at 
\begin_inset Flex URL
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

https://stackoverflow.com
\end_layout

\end_inset

 where I wanted to add an algorithm float with a program listing inside
 with 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 knitr code not to be executed.
 I found that the module Rnw was interfering with what I wanted.
 Thus, a workaround to be able to display the whole code using an algorithm
 float a plain box from LyX.
 In this minimal working example I show how I achieved a less than optimal
 solution.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
A simple 
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
textsf{R}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 code chunk
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

1+1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
That one ran OK.
 Let's create a program listing to display the complete code of the above
 chunk using an Algorithm float using a Program Listing as in 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "didntwork"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset

:
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float algorithm
wide false
sideways false
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset listings
inline false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

1+1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
This one didn't work
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "didntwork"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
If you run this with the Rnw module it wont work...
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
A very nasty workaround
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Instead of adding a Program Listing in the float, add a Frameless Box and
 add the code as plain text as shown in 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "itworked"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float algorithm
wide false
sideways false
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Box Frameless
position "t"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "100col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
thickness "0.4pt"
separation "3pt"
shadowsize "4pt"
framecolor "black"
backgroundcolor "none"
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
<<>>=
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
1+2
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
@
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
A nice algortithm
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "itworked"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Upon running, it's OK...
 Like meh! but it works...
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: I wonder what @yihui would think of this...